# Importrange Data from a sheet, then remove the formula and keep the values

Tags: function, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to get a Google Sheet to import values from one sheet to another. I have figured out how to make a drawing to act as a button, and to trigger the adding of functions like importrange to collect the data.

However, after the data is imported, I would like to be able to sort and edit it free from the importrange formula. Normally I would do this by hand by copying and then pasting the values only, but I want to have that step done as part of the script.

Here is the [mock source sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MAv0PdqaxbNpIivlKM4XHh9-SU3ASvZmV0_-eAeBJ5w/edit#gid=637934803) and the [mock destination sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DWfaOnoFV9uwObOv_pMkElFxy-7e5_JHGDzeC99Or8w/edit#gid=896639595)

Here is what I have for a script:

```
function Cars() {
  fetch();
  Values1();
}

function fetch() {
 var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 spreadsheet.getRange('A4').activate()
.setFormula('=Query(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MAv0PdqaxbNpIivlKM4XHh9-SU3ASvZmV0_-eAeBJ5w/edit#gid=637934803","\' Master List\'!$B$3:$H"),"select Col4,Col2,Col7,Col5 where Col4 is not null order by Col4 asc")');

var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
spreadsheet.getRange('I4').activate()
.setFormula('=Query(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MAv0PdqaxbNpIivlKM4XHh9-SU3ASvZmV0_-eAeBJ5w/edit#gid=637934803","\' Master List\'!$B$3:$H"),"select Col1 where Col4 is not null order by Col4 asc")');

}


function Values1() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A4:D121').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A4:D121').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
}
```

When I run this, I can get the data to import, but I can't get the data to be values only. There is probably a better way to do this, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing your last two lines with:

```
spreadsheet.getRange('A4:D121').setValues(spreadsheet.getRange('A4:D121').getValues());
```

Comment: I tried this, but then what happens is the data doesn't get added to the sheet. It's almost like the function runs so fast the data never gets there before it is erased.

Comment: Add `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` in between the two callings of functions inside Cars(). It should wait for fetch() to be finished until launching values1()

Comment: or add some miliseconds for waiting the IMPORTRANGE to calculate. `Utilities.sleep(milliseconds)`

Comment: The spreadsheetapp.flush worked like a charm!!  Thanks!!!